# java : how to use an ocr with 64 bits windows

Tags: java, ocr, windows-7-x64, tesseract

i am trying to build a web application allowing the user to upload an image text and convert it into text file retrieving the text from it

to do this i search the web looking for an open source java **OCR** i found tesseract , javaOCR , aspire( but only trial version ) tess4j etc

tesseract OCR is highly recommended but doesn't have a **java** 64 bits version

The reason I need a 64 bit version is that I'm using it as part of a Java project that requires a 64-bit JVM. The 32 bit version of Tesseract clearly won't work in the 64 bit JVM

is there a version of tesseract ocr working on windows 64 bits ?

Comment: What kind of error, or issued you had when u tried to use an ocr with 64 windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 64-bit Tesseract and Leptonica DLLs available from [Tesseract .NET wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/tree/master/src/lib/TesseractOcr/x64) project. You can use them together with [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sf.net).

Comment: This worked for me, using 64-bit JVM and Windows 8, with eclipse. Had to double check what -bit JVM I was actually using in eclipse by calling `System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")`